# Store link class for future pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an index page, with 4 links on it. Let's give them numerical values of 1, 2, 3 & 4.

Whatever link I click, I'd like to store the class of that link and echo that value it on all future pages, until I return to the index page and start again.

So if I click link 2, a 2 will be displayed on that page, but then if I go from page 2 to page 4, a 2 will continue to be displayed.

Sorry for lack of code or logic, brain is fried.

Comment: Assuming this isn't a single page application. You might want to look into session storage for passing info between pages on the client side. http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Who downvoted this? I dare you to show yourself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those cases I always suggest to use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). [It works on all major browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) e.g.:

```
$('.mylinks').on("click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("current-link", this.className); // You can check for 'current-link' at Dev Tools(F12) -> Resources (Chrome)
});
```

The logic is, when link is clicked, you store its class. It will be available through pages. If you want the data to be store only on the current session, you can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) as well.

Comment: You were quicker than I was. +1

Comment: And I was being lazy and just commented and posted a link.